# How to index rows with duplicate values in a column?

Tags: mysql, count, duplicates

How can I count the duplicates in `Phone`?

For eg:

```
State   Zip Areacode    Phone
A       123 1           989
b       234 2           989
c       345 3           989
d       456 4           123
e       567 5           123
f       678 6           234
g       678 7           234
```

Expected result:

```
State   Zip Areacode    Phone   row_count
A       123 1           989     1
b       234 2           989     2
c       345 3           989     3
d       456 4           123     1
e       567 5           123     2
f       678 6           234     1
g       678 7           234     2
```

Comment: What is your MySQL version ?

Comment: So you want to have row index, not how much total same item there is?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I've the SQL Version of SQLyog Ultimate - MySQL GUI 8.5

Comment: @Justinas Yes I want how many duplicates count with the index like 1,2,3

Comment: Please give version of your MySQL server, not the client you are using to connect to it.

Comment: How is row_count defined within a "partition" of phone ? Which row will have row_count = 1 for same phone no ?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Yes if the Phone number has 3 duplicate records its shows row count like 1,2,3

Comment: @Gowtham that part is clear. But how do you decide which row to give 1, which one 2 and so on..

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya That's not a problem, Whatever the number order is OK but I want the count of the duplicates. Hope now you understand. I think

Comment: What @MadhurBhaiya is getting at is that, depending on your version of MySQL, the answer will be different. If you have MySQL 8, the solution will be trivial, using window functions. Otherwise, the solution will be a bit more complicated. We need to know which version so we can give you an appropriate solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [Window function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html) problem. For older MySQL versions (**< 8.0**), we can emulate it using [Session variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html). Try the following:

```
SELECT t1.State, 
       t1.Zip, 
       t1.Areacode, 
       @row_count := CASE 
                       WHEN @ph = t1.Phone Then @row_count + 1
                       ELSE 1 
                     END AS row_count, 
       @ph := t1.Phone AS Phone 
FROM 
  (SELECT State, 
          Zip, 
          Areacode, 
          Phone 
   FROM your_table 
   ORDER BY Phone) AS t1  
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @row_count := 1) AS init1 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @ph := '') AS init2
```

**PS:** OP has [confirmed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52739254/how-can-i-count-the-duplicates-in-mysql/52741152#comment92404933_52739254) that numbering within a partition of `Phone` can be anything.

Comment: @Gowtham happy to help :) I hope you can make sense out of query, on what and how it is doing ! If explanation needed, let me know. Read this to get an idea: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution if you are ordering by phone number is:

```
SELECT State, Zip, Areacode, Phone, `Index` FROM (
    SELECT State, 
           Zip, 
           Areacode, 
           Phone, 
           @Idx := IF(@previous_phone=Phone, IFNULL(@Idx,0)+1,1) as Index,
           @previous_phone := Phone
    FROM table 
    ORDER BY Phone
) t;
```

This will just keep the track of the previous phone number and reset the index if it changes.

If you want to count duplicates for the combination Zip Area Phone then you can compare based on `CONCAT(Zip,Area,Phone)` e.g.

```
SELECT State, Zip, Areacode, Phone, `Index` FROM (
    SELECT State, 
           Zip, 
           Areacode, 
           Phone, 
           @Idx := IF(@previous_phone=CONCAT(Zip, Area, Phone), IFNULL(@Idx,0)+1,1) as Index, 
           @previous_phone := CONCAT(Zip, Area, Phone)
    FROM table 
    ORDER BY Zip, Area, Phone
) t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the MySQL query to find duplicate records by comparing multiple columns

```html
SELECT 
    Zip, COUNT(Zip),
    Areacode,  COUNT(Areacode),
    Phone,      COUNT(Phone)
FROM
    TableName
GROUP BY 
    Zip , 
    Areacode , 
    Phone
HAVING  COUNT(Zip) > 1
    AND COUNT(Areacode) > 1
    AND COUNT(Phone) > 1;
```

Replace TableName form your Mysql table name.

[Reference](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-find-duplicate-values/)

Comment: This query does not return what OP is asking for. Since you're grouping by all but 3 of the columns (and no row has duplicates across those 3 columns), no rows are returned.